# Sub 10 height request layouts/views not allowed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to add line dividers between views. However, there is a forced margin on every element I try (Image, BoxView, Frame, Label). I set the margin to be 0, the HeightRequest is always 3, but as you can see the view bounds expand past the actual view. Is there a specific view I'm supposed to be using? I just want the gray line and nothing more.

```
var line2 = new Frame
{
    WidthRequest = (App.ScreenDpWidth / 2),
    MinimumHeightRequest = 3,
    HeightRequest = 3,
    BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#229EBB"),
    Margin = new Thickness(0, 0)
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are layouting your elements either in a `Grid` or a `StackLayout`.

By default, the `StackLayout.Spacing`, `Grid.RowSpacing` and `Grid.ColumnSpacing` properties are set to `6d`.

Without more information, I think that's what you're seeing in your code. Change those values to `0d`.

Also, if you only want a gray line, you can use a `BoxView` which will draw a gray box, and set it's Height to `1d`.